# Misunderstanding with asBoolean method of Matcher class

Tags: java, groovy

I have a problem with a tiny testing script:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

cfgText = "PATTERN1 = 9\nPATTERN2 = 136.225.73.44\nPATTERN3 = 136.225.236.12"

cfgLine = cfgText.split('\n');
def p = /.*PATTERN2.*/;
def PATTERN2_found = false;
for (i=0; PATTERN2_found==false && i < cfgLine.length; i++)
{
    println("cfgLine" +i+ ": " + cfgLine[i]);
    def m = cfgLine[i] =~ p;
    println("m: " + m)
    println("m.asBoolean(): " + m.asBoolean());
    println("m: " + m)
    println("m.asBoolean(): " + m.asBoolean());
    if(m.asBoolean()){
        println("Heeeyyyy");
    }
    println("--------------------------------");
}
```

This is its output:

```
cfgLine0: PATTERN1 = 9
m: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*PATTERN2.* region=0,12 lastmatch=]
m.asBoolean(): false
m: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*PATTERN2.* region=0,12 lastmatch=]
m.asBoolean(): false
--------------------------------
cfgLine1: PATTERN2 = 136.225.73.44
m: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*PATTERN2.* region=0,24 lastmatch=]
m.asBoolean(): true
m: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*PATTERN2.* region=0,24 lastmatch=PATTERN2 = 136.225.73.44]
m.asBoolean(): false
--------------------------------
cfgLine2: PATTERN3 = 136.225.236.12
m: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*PATTERN2.* region=0,25 lastmatch=]
m.asBoolean(): false
m: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*PATTERN2.* region=0,25 lastmatch=]
m.asBoolean(): false
--------------------------------

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor$1 (file:/usr/share/groovy/lib/groovy-2.4.15.jar) to constructor java.util.regex.Matcher()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

As you can see the regular expression matches in the second loop but the behaviour is strange for me. I really don't know why if I use TWO times `asBoolean` against the same Matcher object, the result is different. Does it have an internal iterator or something like that?

PS: I've resolved this using `==~` operator, but I would like to know why asBoolean works like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens, because `StringGroovyMethods.asBoolean(Matcher matcher)` calls `matcher.find()` which modifies internal state of the matcher.

```java
/**
 * Coerce a Matcher instance to a boolean value.
 *
 * @param matcher the matcher
 * @return the boolean value
 * @since 1.7.0
 */
public static boolean asBoolean(Matcher matcher) {
    if (null == matcher) {
        return false;
    }

    RegexSupport.setLastMatcher(matcher);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

> *Source: [src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.java](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.java#L90-L104)*

This is why when you call `m.asBoolean()` for the first time it returns `true`, because its state before this call was (no matching found):

```
m: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*PATTERN2.* region=0,24 lastmatch=]
```

And now when you call `m.asBoolean()` for the second time, matcher object is modified by the previous call and is represented by:

```
m: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.*PATTERN2.* region=0,24 lastmatch=PATTERN2 = 136.225.73.44]
```

And it returns `false`, because there is no other part that satisfies the matcher.

Comment: Thanks!! However, in my opinion, it is an strange behaviour because with the name "asBoolean" seems like I only want to know whether it has any match or not. The name of the method doesn't represent that I am going to modify the original object. Do you have the same feeling?

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is confusing and there should be no side-effects when calling `asBoolean()` method. I have reported it as a bug (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8855) and working on a fix, which is fairly simple. Thanks for catching this corner case!